# Cascading flexbox not placing content after first box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having an issue with cascading flexbox. I have:

- One column flexbox to place first my content, then my footer with space-between (so footer is at the bottom of the page)
- Content is row flexbox, placing a menu on the left, and the payload on the right.

In my example below, it works well in "situation 1", when there is no scrollbar. Content is at the bottom of the page/container. In situation 2, the footer is placed a the bottom of the view (based on the initial scroll) and above the content, and remains at the small place when I scroll. My goal would be to have it only appear after the content. I played with min-height, height, max-height in different configuration but I seem to replace an issue by another one when I change them.

```css
#content1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="content1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <div>
        menu
      </div>
      <div>
        Situation 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      footer 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <div>
        menu
      </div>
      <div>
        Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      footer 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have `height: 0` on the `.container`? When you remove that the layout seems to work.

Comment: Without the height:0, problem is solved for situation2, but now situation 1 has a scrollbar that is not necessary

Comment: Because you need to apply the adjustment to only the second container. Try this: `#content2 > .container { height: auto }`. https://jsfiddle.net/ounL0kuj/

Comment: Unfortunatly, the content will be dynamic, so i need the same stylesheet to work in both situations

Comment: Instead of `justify-content` use an `auto` margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#content1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
}
.footer { margin-top: auto; } /* NEW */
```

```html
<div id="content1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <div>menu</div>
      <div>Situation 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <div>menu</div>
      <div>
        Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>Situation 2
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```